# Can open Google Play not exist app with nfc tag in android

Tags: android, tags, nfc

Hello I left the table  NFC tag that I created for the cafe to download the application. I want them touched directly to customers opening in Google Play. But when it is not at all an installed application. Is this possible. as like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jl4vMeHSYnI

Comment: You can check this link http://www.creativebloq.com/android/getting-started-nfc-android-5122811 sounds good. Happy coding.

Comment: its nice sample but not complated code

Comment: Thanks is solution my problems

Comment: Anytime happy coding :D. If the answer below was good help please accept it fr it would help the community. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get app URL on Google Play, for instance for WhatsApp it's : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp

And you write this URL on an NFC tag in NDEF format, you could use for instance this app to write tag: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter
You choose : Write tags > New Dataset > Link, you put a title (optionaly), the URL, and click Save & Write

**UPDATE1**

If you want to develop app to write NDEF tag, please have a look at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html

in particular http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#creating-records & http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar

Comment: @Ferandro, Is it useful ?

Comment: I have one problem can you help mi for xml pars in spinner in android

Comment: can you sent me email address

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959435/how-can-take-services-xml-data-in-android-spinner-by-adi-as-like-below-pictures