# How to populate Spinner from XML data

Tags: android, xml, service

Data comes from an XML web-service response:
[image]

How to populate Spinner with "Adi" values from XML ?

Comment: This question is really hard to understand. What exactly is the problem? What do you try to solve?

Comment: I wanto display xml parse item in spinner

Answer (score 0):

To parse XML data, please follow this:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

To populate spinner with parsed data, please follow this: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: @Ferandro, Is it useful ?